# using kube-proxy for load balancing

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-proxy

The [official kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#shortcomings) clearly state that **kube-proxy** *"will not scale to very large clusters with thousands of Services"*, however when a `LoadBalancer` type Service is created on GKE the `externalTrafficPolicy` is set to `Cluster` by default (meaning that each request will be load-balanced by kube-proxy anyway in addition to external load balancing). As it is explained for example in [this video from Next '17](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2bhV81MfKQ&t=1823), this is to avoid traffic imbalance (as Google's external load balancers are not capable of asking a cluster how many pods of a given service are on each node).

Hence the question: does it mean that:

a) by default GKE cannot be used for for "very large clusters with thousands of Services" and to do so I need to risk traffic imbalances by setting `externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local`

b) ...or the information about poor scalability of kube-proxy is incorrect or outdated

c) ...or something else that I couldn't come up with

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`will not scale to very large clusters with thousands of services` quote refers to userspace proxy, which was the default mode long time ago before full iptables based implementation happened. So this statement is largely outdated, but...

iptables mode has it's own issues that come with scale (extreamly large iptables rule chains take a lot of time to update) which is one of the reasons why IPVS work made it into kube-proxy. You'd have to have a really hardcore scale to run into performance issues with kube-proxy.

Comment: To add to this - we regularly test both Kubernetes in general and GKE specifically with thousands of services and hundreds of thousands of pods.  GKE has customers using multi-thousand node clusters in production.

Comment: @TimHockin and Radek: Thanks for your help guys! So it seems that the answer should be c: I'm clumsy and didn't notice that the quote is for the legacy mode only ;-] Maybe it would be better if it was placed right after the explanation of modes in ["Virtual IPs and service proxies" section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies) as the place it is now seems out of context of proxy modes and misleads clumsy ppl like me ;-]

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Kubernetes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) about externalTrafficPolicy the answer is a).

Since Cluster option ***obscures the client source IP and may cause a second hop to another node, but should have good overall load-spreading***, and Local option ***preserves the client source IP and avoids a second hop for LoadBalancer and NodePort type services, but risks potentially imbalanced traffic spreading.***